# Adding a background image to an SSRS 2012 report

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am trying to add an image so that it will work as a background for my ssrs report.  I would also like it so that it doesn't cover up anything on the report, like in Word when you wrap an image to go behind the text. And is there a setting that would have the image fit to the entire page? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In report design view, select the report item to which you want to add a background image.

If the Properties pane is not visible, on the View tab, select Properties.

In the Properties pane, expand BackgroundImage, and then do the following:

For an embedded image:

Set Source to Embedded.

Set Value to the name of an image that is embedded in the report.

For an external image:

Set Source to External.

Set Value to a valid path to an image. This can be on a report server in native mode or SharePoint integrated mode, or it can be on any other Web site

For an image is that is contained in a field in the database to which the report item is connected:

Set Source to Database.

Set Value to the name of a field in the report dataset

For MIMEType, or file format, select the appropriate MIME type for the image-for example, .bmp.

For BackgroundRepeat, select an expression, Default, Repeat, RepeatX, or RepeatY, or Clip.

For background images in a chart, BackgroundRepeat can be set to Default, Repeat, Fit, and Clip, but not RepeatX or RepeatY.

Thanks.